# Can't use firebase db to build chrome extension in manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to build a chrome extension that uses firebase as a db in my `content.js` file but it doesn't work. I am using `v3` manifest. But I am unable to import firebase.

I tried setting up firebase in my project using this [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup). I also tried downloading the source code from [firebase-app.js](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js) and [firebase-database.js](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js), and imported it using

```
const firebase = chrome.extension.getURL('./firebase-app.js');
```

but this file has imports from

```
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js
```

this violates the `content_security_policy` and I get this error

```
Refused to load the script ‘https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js’ because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: “script-src ‘self’ ‘wasm-unsafe-eval’“. Note that ‘script-src-elem’ was not explicitly set, so ‘script-src’ is used as a fallback.
```

I am aware of the [external code restrictions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code).

Is there any workaround for this in vanilla JS implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the ECRs state, you cannot load these scripts from a CDN.

Instead you must install a JavaScript build pipeline (such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/)) to compile an application bundle of your extension's code.

Firebase has [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling) on this process and link to relevant resources that are worth reviewing.

Comment: Would it be best to use reactjs instead of vanilla js to build the extension?